# What is the preferred way of persisting data across web socket connections in server memory?

Tags: node.js, websocket, server, socket.io, storage

I am making a multiplayer game using web sockets. I'd like client sockets to send data to the server, which is then persisted as part of the game state for a specific room for the session. Other sockets in this room can both access and modify this data.

What is the recommended way to store this data?

What I'm currently doing is storing data for a specific room as properties on a "live" reference to the room, via the io adapter and Map.prototype.get method. A simplified example of this is below:

```
//Socket.IO server

io.on('connection`, async socket => {
  const { roomId, data1} = socket.handshake.query;
  await socket.join(roomId);
  const store = io.adapter.rooms.get(roomId);
  (store.data = store.data || []).push(data1)

  socket.on('request-data', () => {
    io.to(roomId).emit('show-data', store.data1)
  });
})
```

So, this way, each roomId is associated with it's own store,  all new socket connections get access to the store.data for the roomId they provide, and these same sockets can modify the actual store object. The downside IMO is that the actual store is pretty nested and requires the Map.get() method to get access to the live reference.

It just seems to me there should be more formal, well-defined way to persist data between socket connections on the server. Is there a preferred or better way to do this?

Comment: Use a database, based on the type of data you are going to store. It can be something like MySQL, Redis or MongoDB. Also, consider the performance of the database; since, it's a game, you need fast read and write speed.

Comment: @Rajan Yes, eventually I would use Redis if requiring multiple socket servers. MongoDB too slow AFAIK for read-writing in real-time game. But right now, I'm still learning, and would like to know if there exists a proper way to do this in the context of single server. I'd like to keep things in memory for performance reasons.

Comment: It's hard to make any recommendation here. "Better" is a very relative and broad term that depends on the use case.

Comment: I agree with @ggorlen. Though, if you want to separate the data storage process, then you should use "node-cache" package (the easy way) or create a custom control mechanism yourself for in-memory caching (see this stackoverflow.com/a/46049441/13460667)